# Magento - submit invoice event and price comparison

Tags: magento, invoice, dispatchevent

all!

I'm trying to compare prices, in Order, such as GrandTotal and TotalPaid, after submit invoice.
i'm try listen "sales_order_invoice_save_after" event.

```
config.xml
...
<events>
    <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
        <observers>
            <orderapi>
                <class>orderapi/observer</class>
                <method>checkInvoiceSubmit</method>
            </orderapi>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
</event>
...
```

and next step:

```
Observer.php
 public function checkInvoiceSubmit(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
 {
    $event = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$paid = $event->getState();
        if($paid == 2) {
        echo $paid."<br/>";
     }
    var_dump("Grand ".$event->getGrandTotal());
    var_dump("Paid ".$event->getTotalPaid());
    var_dump("Due ".$event->getTotalDue());
    var_dump("Refunden "$event->getTotalRefunden());

    die;
}
```

and see:
Grand 89.97,
Paid NULL,
DUE NULL,
Refunden NULL.

input:
Grand Total     £89.97,
Total Paid  £0.00,
Total Refunded  £0.00,
Total Due   £89.97.

How do I properly compare the two prices(Grand and Total) after confirmation of payment?

Comment: There are [next get*total methods in invoice](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wKbB1.png). Which of them do you need?

Comment: I need to compare Grand Total and Total Paid... But after invoice submit i have Total Paid NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder();
```

Enjoy!